# Wrong values in launch configuration

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to run a Node.js app in US South which was deployed in Germany before.

**manifest.yml**:

```
applications:
- name: ISICC IDES
  disk_quota: 1024M
  host: isiccides
  command: node server.js
  path: .
  instances: 1
  memory: 256M
  domain: mybluemix.net
```

I create a new launch configuration.

1. Under **Spaces** I'm still offered the Germany spaces.
2. **Domain** is set to eu-de.mybluemix.net, which I can not change.

Comment: What type of account?

Comment: account type: internal trial

Comment: Hace you changed the API endpoint?

Comment: I set the „Target“ field of the launch configuration to „US South“. Not sure if anything else needs to be changed.

Comment: You need to set the API to https://api.ng.bluemix.net.  (cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net)

Comment: I ran cf api api.ng.bluemix.net in my terminal. However, in the Web IDE I am still presented the eu-de spaces and can not change the domain from eu-de to ng. What am I missing?